# false = true problem when solving Lemma in Coq

Tags: coq

I have definition:

```
Definition f (b1 b2 : bool) :bool := 
match b1 with  
| true => true
| false => b2
end.
```

And Lemma...

```
Lemma l1: forall p : bool, f p false = true.
```

What I have tried is this:

```
Lemma l1: forall p : bool, f p false = true.
Proof.
intros p.
destruct p.
simpl.
reflexivity.
simpl.
```

And then I get false=true. What to do?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot prove `l1`, since `f false false = false`.

Perhaps you would like to prove:

```
Lemma l1: forall p : bool, f p false = p.
```

instead.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the definition was n ot good. Here it is.

```
Definition f (b1 b2 : bool) : bool := 
  match b1, b2 with  
  | false, true => false
  | _, _ => true
  end.
```

And then I did proof in this way. Am I right?

```
Lemma l1: forall p : bool, f p false = true.
Proof.
intros p.
destruct p.
simpl.
reflexivity.
simpl.
reflexivity.
Qed.
```

Comment: Your proof is correct. Using tacticals, you can make the proof script shorter and more readable:  `Proof. destruct p; reflexivity. Qed.`.  
Please note that it's important not to build proofs about erroneous definitions ...